# Geometric mean of $a_i+b$ ($i=1,\ldots, N$).

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $b$ and $a_i$ be positive real numbers, $i=1,\ldots,N$. Let the geometric mean $G(\{x_i\})=\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^Nx_i}$.

[I know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986278/shifted-geometric-mean) that $G(\{a_i+b\})\geq b+ G(\{a_i\})$, but when does the equality holds? is there a way to write $G(\{a_i+b\})$ as a function of $b$ and $G(\{a_i\})$ (the same way as is the case with the arithmetic mean: $\dfrac{1}{N} \sum (a_i+b)=\dfrac{1}{N}\sum (a_i)+b$)

Comment: With $N=2$ you'll find that $G(\{a_1+b,a_2+b\}) = b+ G(\{a_1,a_2\})$ simplifies to $G(\{a_1,a_2\})=\frac{a_1+a_2}2$. I think this then generalises to larger $N$, where the equality holds when the GM equals the AM. For the second question, you can easily find a counterexample using two sets of $a_i$ with the same GM and then add the same $b$ to get two different GMs.

Comment: One can take $a_i=c_i^N$, then $G(\{a_i\})=\prod c_i$, inequality turns to $\prod (b+c_i^N) \geq (b+\prod c_i)^N$. WLOG one can take $b=1$, because $b$ can be factored out from all $a_i$.